# Android - push notifications: purpose of FirebaseMessagingService class?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've seen two tutorials about sending push messages from server with PHP to android devices through firebase cloud messaging and it works fine. But both tutorials have the FirebaseMessagingService class and I don't understand what's the purpose of it?? They don't explain a bit about it.

This is it:

```
class FirebaseMessagingService : com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService() {

    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage?) {
        showNotification(remoteMessage!!.data["message"]!!)
    }

    private fun showNotification(message: String) {

        val i = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)

        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)

        val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle("FCM Test")
                .setContentText(message)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)

        val manager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

        manager.notify(0, builder.build())
    }
}
```

Can I send push notifications from android with it? I just need to send push messages from PHP so can I delete it? The overview of my project is already messy and hard to follow and I don't want any useless stuff in there. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This class is responsible for handling income message. The function `onMessageReceived` will be invoked when there is incoming `data` message no matter your app is in foreground or background. More specifically, this method is for you to customize the handling of `key:value` pair in `data` payload

You can leave it there if you are not going to do any special handling. 
Please read [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I still don't fully understand it, ok so I won't receive any messages which are sent from PHP any more when I delete this class? What are the options setContentTitle setContentText for? In which cases do I need to customize them??

Comment: Yes, you wont receive any message from firebase if you deleted this class. For the two functions you have asked, they are the title and body for the notification you can see in your notification tray. 

There are many use cases that require developer to customize the `onMessageReceived` function. For example, you need to bring the user to a specific page when he tapped the notification. In this case you will want to put some data into the intent and retrieve it in your starting page so that you know where should you go. :)